# How can I start native camera for windows phone in unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, windows-phone

How can I start camera on my phone in unity for windows phone platform?In unity I can start camera using `WebCamTexture` but sometimes crash because when I stop `webCamTexture.Stop()` and start again `webCamTexture.Play()` stop or freeze my application . Exist any solution to start camera with a plugin or external command or how can I write a method in `MainPage.xaml.cs` and call in unity to start. Any solution is appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

WebCamTexture is not the best solution in my opinion.
I suggest you to considerate some external plugin for windows mobile native functions.

for my mobile apps i use this: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30136

is not heavy, work on wp8 android and ios and is not expensive, but there's a lot of native plugin like this in the store, hope this can help you, good luck : )

Comment: on wp10? or win pc works? exist any solution to start camera?

Comment: can you share solme few line of code where start camera that is all I need.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand... if you want to start your camera in windows phone you need a plugin for native function on windows phone, not just "few line of code"...

Comment: sorry I have a question: you try to open camera on windows phone with this plugin?  @Samuel C.

Comment: nope i tried android and ios, unfortunately i don't build for wp8, but in the plug-in specs seems like windows phone is supported. Btw like i said there are many plug-in like this and all of them can do the job